# How can I select records from a table that are constrained by values on another?

Tags: sql

I'm a SQL newbie and I've run into a problem that I'm not sure how to solve. I have a table of Sites, and each Site has a number of associated Reports in their own table. One field of the Report table is the answer to a Yes/No question.

I want to identify Sites that have on No's for answers in their Report.

```
SELECT * FROM Sites
INNER JOIN Reports ON Sites.ID = Reports.ID
WHERE Reports.Answer = 'No'
```

Of course this will identify all of the reports with an answer of No, but I don't want to include any Site that has a Yes on any Report.

Comment: Have you tried running this code? It should ONLY get reports where the answer is No and ignore anything else. You've pretty much answered your own question.

Comment: @Stewartside, not if a site can have more than one report.

Comment: Right, that's exactly the issue. Sites can have multiple reports. Thank you both for taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT EXISTS():

```
SELECT * FROM Sites
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Reports WHERE Sites.ID = Reports.ID
AND Reports.Answer <> 'No')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Sites S 
WHERE S.ID NOT IN 
          (
          SELECT *
          FROM Sites S 
          WHERE S.ID 
          JOIN Reports R 
          ON S.ID = R.ID
          WHERE R.Answer = 'No'
          )
```